# Setting up mutt

Tags: exchange-server, mutt

I am a newbie to linux and need some help on using mutt for my office MS exchange server.

I have installed mutt 1.5.23 with configure options: `--enable-imap --with-ssl` and `--enable-hcache`.

I think, I am able to login to my exchange account, but can not go beyond (read or send mails). Mutt logs in and then says connection closed with message

> --Mutt: (no mailbox) [Msgs:0] --- (date/date) ----------(all)

Is there a problem with my `.muttrc` or `.msmtprc`? I have no idea. I am pasting contents of both the files:

.muttrc:

```
source /usr/local/etc/Muttrc
set realname = "Ashish Goel"
set from = "ashish.goel@abc.com"
set envelope_from = yes
set imap_user = "ashish.goel@abc.com" 
set folder = "imaps://owa.abc.com/owa/INBOX"
set imap_authenticators = "login"
set mbox = "imaps://owa.abc.com/owa/INBOX"
set spoolfile = "imaps://owa.abc.com/owa/INBOX"
set record = "imaps://owa.abc.com/owa/Sent Items"
set postponed = "imaps://owa.abc.com/owa/Drafts"
set copy=yes
set smtp_url = "smtps://ashish.goel@abc.com@owa.abc.com/owa"
mailboxes !
set header_cache = ~/.mutt/headers
set message_cachedir = ~/.mutt/cache/bodies
set certificate_file = /etc/ssl/certs
set imap_check_subscribed = yes
set imap_keepalive = 300
set imap_passive = no
set mail_check = 60
set timeout = 15
set sendmail = "/usr/bin/msmtp"
set ssl_verify_host = no
set ssl_verify_dates = no
```

.msmtprc:

```
account work
host owa.abc.com/owa
port 587
from ashish.goel@abc.com
user ashish.goel@abc.com
auth ntml
tls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
logfile ~/.msmtp.log
ntlmdomain MYDOMAIN
protocol smtp
account default : work
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with an Exchange 2010 server both on this and later versions of mutt. In the end, I found the problem went away after I reset my subscribed folders in IMAP. I did this by using our web mail gateway which also uses IMAP. If you don't have such a facility, try the tips [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Download-an-IMAP-folder-list-bd7e4e70-79ec-4726-8469-1a0577ef34e2) to generate a list of subscribed folders, change it, and see if the updated list now works for you..

Answer (score 0):

These are my functioning configuration files:

.muttrc:

```
set sendmail="/usr/bin/esmtp"
set envelope_from=yes
set realname="Kitone Elvis Peter"
set from="Kitone Elvis Peter <elviskitone@gmail.com>"
set use_from=yes
set edit_headers=yes
set smtp_url = "smtp://elviskitone@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:587/"
set smtp_pass =""
set imap_user = "elviskitone@gmail.com"
set imap_pass = ""
set mail_check = 30
set move = no
set imap_keepalive = 900
set header_cache = "~/.mutt/cache/headers"
set message_cachedir = "~/.mutt/cache/bodies"
set certificate_file = "~/.mutt/certificates"
set folder = "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993"
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"
```

I used esmtprc instead of msmtprc.

.esmtprc:

```
identity "elviskitone@gmail.com"
hostname "smtp.gmail.com:587"
username "elviskitone@gmail.com"
password ""
starttls required
```

You also need to enable IMAP on your email if you haven't already. Plus, you need to give access to insecure or third party applications on your email, in email settings.